# Not allowed to close a window after clicking the icon on the laucher

Tags: unity, launcher, icons

After clicking the icon of the application on the launcher I am not allowed to close when hovering over one of the windows and it is not focusing on the one my mouse is over,and I saw that it is possible on other computers. Is there some setting I should check in order to have that? I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

This is the scenario am talking about:

[image]

Comment: Did you make any modifications to your Compiz configuration?

Comment: No , I did not.

Answer (score 0):

Press Alt+F2, and then type "xkill" ... it will give you a cursor to force whatever window you want closed. Especially useful when "sudo kill " does nothing from the command line. If this is common problem for you (i've never seen firefox behave that way), then there might be something wrong with your installation.

Comment: That happens for all windows not just for Firefox and I just want to close one minimized window if I have more open from the same app and xkill does not work for me in this case.

Comment: Weird. Something bigger is going on. When did it start happening? What has changed recently?